# How to change a useState's object value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

After getting member data, `member` state will be like this.

```
{
  _id: '61d34027ca50827501279eb0',
  index: 1,
  email: 'bcr90348@zwoho.com',
  name: '1',
  active: true
}
```

How to change the values of the above object by changing the text box values?

Ex: Changing the name. Changing email.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
  CButton,
  CCard,
  CCardBody,
  CCardHeader,
  CCol,
  CForm,
  CFormInput,
  CFormLabel,
  CRow,
} from '@coreui/react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Edit = (props) => {
  const id = props.match.params.id
  const [member, setMember] = useState({})

  const handleLoadMember = async () => {
    try {
      const _data = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/v1/member/${id}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        },
      })

      if (_data.status === 200) {
        const data = await _data.json()
        setMember(data.member)
      } else if (_data.status === 404) {
      } else {
        throw new Error()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleLoadMember()
  }, [])

  return (
    <CRow>
      <CCol xs={12}>
        <CCard className="mb-4 w-75">
          <CCardHeader>
            <strong>Add New Member</strong>
          </CCardHeader>
          <CCardBody>
            <p className="text-medium-emphasis small">
              Click on save button after editing member details.
            </p>
            <CForm>
              <div className="d-inline-flex w-100">
                <div className="mb-3 me-1 w-50">
                  <CFormLabel>Email:</CFormLabel>
                  <CFormInput
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="name@example.com"
                    value={member.email}
                    onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3 w-50">
                  <CFormLabel>Name:</CFormLabel>
                  <CFormInput type="text" placeholder="Perera's Home" value={member.name} />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <CButton color="primary">Submit</CButton>
              </div>
            </CForm>
          </CCardBody>
        </CCard>
      </CCol>
    </CRow>
  )
}

Edit.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.any,
}

export default Edit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an `onChangeHandler` like below. And add define `name` prop to each field.

```
  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setMember((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  };
```

```
<CFormInput
    type="email"
    placeholder="name@example.com"
    name="email"
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    value={member.email}
 />
```

```
<CFormInput
     type="text"
     placeholder="Perera's Home"
     name="name"
     onChange={onChangeHandler}
     value={member.name}
 />
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-moore-4xts4?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I didn't use prevState and how is this working? `onChange={(e) => {setMember({ ...member, email: e.target.value })}}`

Comment: `setMemeber` accepts either value (object, array, number, string) or a callback function which is called with the previous state value.

Comment: Thank you! I prefer to select your answer as the accepted answer as this is more declarative.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that `member` already has a value (like you described in your question), you can alter one or multiple properties of it by doing something like this with the spread operator:

```
setMember(member => ({...member, name: "My New Name", email: "NewEmail"}))
```

See the [Hooks API and useState documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) for more information.